# Brakeman error parse error on value ')' as a result of updated syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I have recently installed brakeman and ran the gem on my system. One error it is picking up is in relation to what I believe is a parenthesis.

The line of code it is picking an error up on is:

```
%p=link_to("Click here", url_for(only_path: false, host: ConfigSetting.get("FORGET_PASSWORD_HOST_PREFIX","localhost"), account_new_passwd_reset_path(key: @guid)))
```

I have recently updated syntax which required an extra parenthesis after the 'account_new_passwd_path'. I believe this is the issue but I cannot understand why.

The outdated code I had was:

```
%p=link_to("Click here", url_for(:only_path=>false, :host=>ConfigSetting.get("FORGET_PASSWORD_HOST_PREFIX","localhost"), :controller=>:account, :action=>:new_passwd_reset, :key=>@guid))
```

As you can see in terms of the routing it is the biggest change around the key @guid area.
Any ideas?

The error I am receiving is 'Error: app/views/passwd_reset_mailer/password_reset.haml:3 :: parse error on value ")" (tRPAREN) Could not parse app/views/passwd_reset_mailer/password_reset.haml'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of arguments. Keyword arguments need to be at the end of the argument list. But then there is another issue that using a url helper together with `url_for` doesn't really makes sense.

Just change:

```
%p=link_to(
     "Click here", 
     url_for(
       only_path: false, 
       host: ConfigSetting.get("FORGET_PASSWORD_HOST_PREFIX","localhost"), 
       account_new_passwd_reset_path(key: @guid)
     )
   )
```

to

```
%p=link_to(
     "Click here", 
     account_new_passwd_reset_url(
       host: ConfigSetting.get("FORGET_PASSWORD_HOST_PREFIX","localhost"), 
       key: @guid
     )
   )
```

Please note the `_url` instead of the `_path` suffix, which test Rails to build a full URL including the hostname.

Comment: Thanks so much. The changes listed above worked perfectly. I ran brakeman again to check for errors and the error is gone. Good spot on the url_helper issue. Appreciate it.